# Neo4j Spatial version to use with Neo4j 1.8.2

Tags: neo4j

What version of spatial do I use with Neo4j 1.8.2?

Tried building it by just changing the neo4j.version:
 1.8.2

but got a bunch of compile errors.

Either building it/getting the jars and server plugin from somewhere would be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Just released it](http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases/org/neo4j/neo4j-spatial/0.9-neo4j-1.8.2/): `org.neo4j:neo4j-spatial:0.9-neo4j-1.8.2`

Please try and report back.

Comment: Michael you're a life saver :-) Thank you, I'll try it out and let you know.